# HTML / inputs elements in the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put some input elements (~7) in the same line.

I have the following code:

```
<form>
  <b> One </b>
 <input type="number" style = "width: 5%; vertical-align:top" class="form-control"  name="quantity" value="1" >
</form>
<form>
  <b> Two </b>
  <input type="number" style = "width: 5%; vertical-align:top" class="form-control"  name="quantity" value="1" >
</form>
<form>
  <b> Three</b>
  <input type="number" style = "width: 5%; vertical-align:top" class="form-control"  name="quantity" value="1" >
</form>
```

The problem is that every input every input has it own line, and it not in the same line.

Edit: Also, I wish that it will be with space in that way that the inputs elements would comprehend the whole line.
Hoe can I do it?

Comment: Get all your input into the same form.

Comment: @Veve: It still makes line for each input

Comment: Set every form tag style="display: inline;"

Comment: `the inputs elements would comprehend the whole line` Not sure what you mean by this

Comment: @MLeFevre: Sorry. I mean that between each input element would be equal spaces, so the input elements would be on the entire row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input elements should all share the same form, and your styling can be modified & put into CSS, which will simplify your code significantly.

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4utpu6c/

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="number" />
<input type="number" />
<input type="number" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
input {
display: inline;
width: 5%; 
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I do equal spaces between each input? so the last input element would be in the end of the line?

Comment: Fiddle has been updated. You'll want to put the inputs in divs, so that the width of the page division is different than the width of the input field. Also, I changed the width of the input field to be in "em" units, which is much better for inputs than percentages.

Answer (score 1):

Change the display, remove the inline styles. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ys1Lgj7e/

```
form {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set every form tag to 'display: inline;'

In that html file:

```
<style>
form {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

OR in your css file:

```
form {
    display: inline;
}
```

OR each  tag :

```
<form style="display: inline;">
```